# authorising pipelines against azure devops service connection

Tags: azure, azure-devops

i am trying to have dedicated service connections per pipeline, so i have removed the "allow all pipelines to use this service connection" and i have pointed a task at the service connection, which works fine. But when i look in the service connection list under "policies" it doesnt show anythinf under "authorized pipelines", from an admin perspective it would be useful to see this. Am i doing something wrong? ive looked all over but cant find anything to suggest what it could be (ive tried in 2 different ado orgs aswell, they have the same issue)

Comment: Just want to confirm can you see the authorized pipeline under policies now? Is below answer is help for you? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Also, do not hesitate to leave comment if you still has puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

This should relevant with our side, and be delayed due to the time.

If some pipelines created and executed not long ago, it will not display under **authorized pipelines** immediately. It needs some time to let it updated in the Service Connection page.

Some old pipeline which exists for several days, could be detected by the server. Then displayed under the **authorized pipelines** pattern:

[image]

Just wait for patience, if these pipeline still not display under **authorized pipelines** pattern. Please raise this issue on our official community: [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21). We would involve the product group to investigate this abnormal issue.